# CSS Selector :last-of-type + [attribute~=value]

Tags: css, css-selectors

Hy, I'm trying to select in my DOM the last div of a certain type, wich content a class call 'visible'.
But it just doesnt work. Here's my code:

```
.section [class ~= "visible"]:last-of-type{
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Is it possible to do it? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: There's no `:last-of-class` selector in CSS. CSS Selectors don't stack; Therefore there's no possible way to select the last element having a certain class.

Comment: Any reason you used a class selector for `.section` but an attribute selector for the visible class? Couldn't you just use class selectors for both?

Comment: Check out [SelectorGadget](http://selectorgadget.com/) it can teach you some nasty css selector combinations :)